# Model transformation from transformation between two frames

Tags: opengl, matrix, computer-vision, projective-geometry

Given:
a) two frames of a moving object and euclidean transformation(rotate + shift) between them which aligns projection of the object on the first frame to its projection on the second frame.
b) model transformation matrix for the first frame;
c) view and projection matrices which are the same for both frames.

How to find model transformation matrix for the second frame?
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: think about how you operate with matrices between two frames. And how you compose two transformations in just one matrix.

Comment: I multiply them, but how can I use it? If I have only shift transformation(without rotation) between frames, I unproject the same point(for example center of the object) on two frames and find shift in a world space. But how can such approach be applied to a more complex transformation?